# top TIME+ Is using a comma delimiter instead of the usual colon. Does this signify different units?

Tags: timestamps, top

I have been running a process for quite a while, so long that the usual TIME+ format in top is not the usual MM:SS.milliseconds. Instead my process time is reported like this

```
   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND    
399419 my_user_name    20   0   70.9g  36.3g  35076 S 21573  1.2 73699,57 python
```

What is the difference between this time format and the normal TOP TIME+ format? Is this Hours,Minutes? All other processes shown in top have the normal MM:SS time, what makes this different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m assuming you’re using `procps-ng`’s `top` (which is typically the case on Linux). This version of `top` [tries to format times using a number of formats](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/52afb3a8d31871d28b1c39573a7ed5196c2d5023/top/top.c#L1715):

1. minutes, seconds, centiseconds (not milliseconds), separated by colons;
2. minutes, seconds, separated by a colon;
3. hours, minutes, separated by a comma (this is the format you’re seeing);
4. hours
5. days
6. weeks

The first of this which fits in the column’s width is used. Your `python` process has used enough time to require the third format; the other processes haven’t.